Azure devops deploy s3 object to elastic beanstalk environment not exist error
I have a nodejs app in git on Azure DevOps. I am deploying to AWS elastic beanstalk using AWS toolkit for Azure DevOps and I am using 2 tasks from there, first to create a new application version using task BeanstalkCreateApplicationVersion and then deploying that version using task BeanstalkDeployApplication. Below is the config that I am using to first upload the file to s3, creating a version and then deploying it:
- task: BeanstalkCreateApplicationVersion@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS'
    regionName: 'eu-west-2'
    applicationName: 'test'
    applicationType: 's3'
    deploymentBundleBucket: 'azure-devops-s3'
    deploymentBundleKey: 'app/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    versionLabel: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    outputVariable: '$(VersionLabelOutput)'

- task: BeanstalkDeployApplication@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS'
    regionName: 'eu-west-2'
    applicationName: 'test'
    environmentName: 'test-env'
    applicationType: 'version'
    versionLabel: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    outputVariable: '$(VersionLabelOutput)'

When this runs, the zip file to s3 uploads fine, a new version is created in the application version page and I can see it in AWS EB application. However when the deploy task runs, I get the error:
##[error]Error: Environment test-env does not exist for the application test

Full error log:
2024-05-27T21:48:58.1337210Z ==============================================================================
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6835860Z Deployment type set to version
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6845889Z Configuring credentials for task
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6857862Z ...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint 'fdcf7bc7-ef55-447f-b7ca-405078d3c310'
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6873904Z ...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint 'fdcf7bc7-ef55-447f-b7ca-405078d3c310'
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6874246Z ...endpoint defines standard access/secret key credentials
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6880524Z Configuring region for task
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6881133Z ...configured to use region eu-west-2, defined in task.
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6958867Z Configuring credentials for task
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6959889Z ...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint 'fdcf7bc7-ef55-447f-b7ca-405078d3c310'
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6963463Z ...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint 'fdcf7bc7-ef55-447f-b7ca-405078d3c310'
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6963902Z ...endpoint defines standard access/secret key credentials
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6964573Z Configuring region for task
2024-05-27T21:48:58.6967920Z ...configured to use region eu-west-2, defined in task.
2024-05-27T21:48:59.0247976Z ##[error]Error: Environment test-env does not exist for the application test
2024-05-27T21:48:59.0284495Z ##[section]Finishing: BeanstalkDeployApplication

These are the permissions that I use in the IAM user for Azure DevOps pipeline:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
                "s3:*",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
                "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


According to the current info you shared, I don't find any issue in the pipeline. To narrow down the issue, you can deploy your app using AWS CLI on your local machine with the same credentials. If there is the same error, check your credentials and environment. Make sure that the environment test-env actually exists in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk console under the application test. Ensure that the environment test-env is in the same region eu-west-2.

Feel free to try it and let me know if there is any issue or update.

After checking via cli, it was narrowed down to a missing permission and was resolved once I added the permission as per my answer below. Thanks

It's great to know the issue resolved. Thanks for sharing the solution.

The issue was IAM user was missing a permission for elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments.
Once this was added, the deployments started to work again and issue was resolved.
